# AIML Implementation for android application

Tags: android, artificial-intelligence, voice, aiml, assistant

I am developing android application using AIML. I am completely new to AIML so I don't know that how can I implement AIML in my application.I found program-ab useful but still in trouble.If any one know how can I do this please give me any guide line regarding this.

Feel free to ask any question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do So , you must use Program O
https://github.com/Program-O/Program-O

, You have to create a PHP mysql server and install program O
Then interface android app to consume rest api

rest json / xml both options are configurable